# FTPS: how does the client obtain the server's certificate when the client is in Implicit TLS mode?

Tags: ftps

I read this on a website about FTPS:

> When connecting to an FTPS server, an FTPS client will first verify
> the trustworthiness of the server’s certificate.

When an FTP client is configured to use FTPS with **Implicit** TLS, how does it obtain the FTP server's certificate?   Could someone please give a step-by-step of what is happening there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Implicit TLS" in FTPS works exactly like TLS in HTTPS and uses the same handshake as browsers do with web servers, for which the steps are explained in various articles:

- https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-happens-in-a-tls-handshake/
- https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/explaining-ssl-handshake/
- https://tls.ulfheim.net/ and https://tls13.ulfheim.net/ – "Every byte of a TLS connection"

Diagram of a TLS 1.2 handshake borrowed from Cloudflare:

[image]

The exact steps differ between TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3, but in common to both, the *actual* first thing done by the client is to send a greeting "ClientHello" message. **The server's response to that message includes the whole certificate** (along with the chosen ciphers and other parameters, as well as a signature made *by* the certificate's private key as proof).

So verifying the certificate is not exactly the first thing that the client does; it's fairly close but your website still simplifies things a bit.

These initial messages in TLS are mostly *not* encrypted; they're used to negotiate the encryption keys using the Diffie-Hellman protocol. The server's certificate is **not used for encryption,** but only to "bind" the DH key-exchange messages to the server's identity and ensure they haven't been tampered with.

(In TLS 1.3, however, the handshake has been changed to finish in fewer steps, and the "Certificate" message sent by the server to the client is actually encrypted. This means that the client can only verify the certificate *after* it has processed the DH key exchange.)

---

In "Explicit TLS" mode, the actual TLS exchange is also identical to the one used in implicit mode, only delayed. Explicit mode starts by first connecting using *cleartext* FTP, then issuing an `AUTH TLS` command to request switching over to TLS mode. After doing so, the client sends a TLS ClientHello and everything continues like "implicit TLS" would.

Comment: At what point does the FTP client obtain the server's SSL certificate so it can be evaluated? And what cert is used to encrypt the ClientHello? Or is the ClientHello in plain text?

Comment: The cert isn't used to encrypt anything at all – the encryption key is negotiated independently. The ClientHello itself is normally not encrypted because it's where the key exchange process *starts,* but the Certificate message *is* encrypted (in the latest TLS version only).